# Can I do a mysql_query in eval()?

Tags: php, mysql, eval

The community builder I am using requires php blocks to be parsed through eval(). Can I use the mysql_query in eval? If not how can I call info from the database in this eval()?

Here's my code so far:

```
$iProId = $this->oProfileGen->_iProfileID;
$sCat = mysql_query("SELECT genres from Profiles WHERE ID = ". $iProId);
print_r($sCat);
```

This gives me:
*Resource id #167*

Comment: Why, exactly, do you need to do this? Both the [`eval`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php) and interpolating a value directly into the query string are potentially huge security holes. There's usually a safer, more performant and more maintainable way than either technique. For SQL statements, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/PDO.prepared-statements) (which means switching to a MySQL extension that supports them, such as PDO). The creator of PHP once said "If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question."

Answer (score 2):

If that code gave you that result when eval'd then yes, you can use mysql_query in eval and the rest of your question boils down to how you would have to use that result set.

In that case I would suggest something like:

```
$iProId = $this->oProfileGen->_iProfileID;
$sCat = mysql_query("SELECT genres from Profiles WHERE ID = ". $iProId);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sCat)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

To loop over all rows in the resultset. If you want to know more the PHP website has all the goods on how to use mysql_* functions.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) (and the other `mysql_fetch_*` functions) for how to get your data from the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Using a query in eval() sounds strange to me, but you code is working right. `mysql_query` returns a mysql resource. Then you need to you `mysql_fetch_array`, `mysql_fetch_row`, or `mysql_fetch_assoc` to read it like:

```
$iProId = $this->oProfileGen->_iProfileID;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT genres from Profiles WHERE ID = ". $iProId);
$sCat = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($sCat);
```